# php preg_replace - replace part of social

Tags: php, regex, replace, mask

I want to find any pattern matching:   `###-##-####`

and replace the `###-##,` with `***-**`

but leave the `-####`

I tried this below, but nothing is being replaced at all.

```
preg_replace('/(^[\d]{3})(-)([\d]{2})(-[\d]{4}$)/','\2\4',$myText);
```

Any help is appreciated

---

Update, here is my entire code string as it currently stands, after trying a few of the suggestions below.  I am comparing the second echo output to the first... and the social numbers all remain the same.

Also, as it was mentioned below, my string does contain more than just a social... it is thousands of characters long. which i think is my real issue.  Sorry if i didnt clear that up in the beginning.

```
    //Make the CSC credit report request.
    $strCscResponse = $Csc->makeRequest($strFixedFormatRecord);

    echo "<br/><br/><pre>" . $strCscResponse  . "</pre><br/><br/>";

    $strCscResponse = str_replace("!", " ", $strCscResponse);

    $strCscResponse = preg_replace('/^\d{3}-\d{2}(-\d{4})$/','***-**$1',$strCscResponse);

    echo "<br/><br/><pre>" . $strCscResponse  . "</pre><br/><br/>";
```

---

*update*

I'd like to mark all the answers and "the answer" just because i didnt clarify the string has more than just a social in it. thank you for the help with this issue, embarrisingly enough it has been driving me wild for a couple days now.

Comment: You say 'any pattern matching...' do you mean in a long string of text? If so, then the beginning and end of line anchors will throw off any match. Additionally, you are not replacing anything with asterisks, which is what your question seems to imply (e.g.: replace `123-45-6789` with `***-**-6789`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one possible problem: you might not be matching the right string (if you are trying to find SSNs buried in a large block of text) - the `^` and `$` anchors will only match beginning of string (or sometimes beginning of line) - if this is not what you want, but instead you want to find SSNs in a long string, you need to get rid of those anchors.

The other problem, potentially, is that you seem to want to replace things with asterisks, but you do not include asterisks in your replacement expression. you need to use a replacement expression like

```
`***-**\4`
```

Comment: that was it.  a lot of other answers alluded to this also, but i didnt know what to put in place of the ^ and $.  Simply removing them fixed the issue.  thanks!

Comment: What does \4 stand for? Thanks

Comment: In this case, `\4` is the text that represents the second dash and the the last four digits of the SSN matched by the regular expression. `\1`, `\2` ... `\9` are called "back-references". It refers to - and represents - some portion of the regular expression that was matched. _TECHNICALLY, it depends upon the implementation as to exactly what is contained in a particular back-reference, such as `\4`;_ however, most often it is the contents of the fourth (4th) set of parentheses `()` in the match expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(\d{3})(-)(\d{2})(-\d{4})
```

Comment: i put that in for my second parameter, but its still not changing anything in my string.  Same thing for Sein Brights suggestion.  I'll post my exact code as an update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/^\d{3}-\d{2}(-\d{4})$/','***-**$1',$myText);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you have ^ and $ in your pattern, but I see no m modifier, so this
   will only match if ###-##-#### is the entire string.
2. [\d] can be
   shortened to \d
3. your \2\4 will leave --####, if you wanted *-####
   you can simply have *\4